# C++ Ifstream reads too much?

Tags: c++, html, file, char, ifstream

I'm trying to read a file and output the contents. Everything works fine, I can see the contents but it seems to add about 14 empty bytes at the end. Does anyone know whats wrong with this code?

```
                    int length;
                    char * html;


                    ifstream is;
                    is.open ("index.html");
                    is.seekg (0, ios::end);
                    length = is.tellg();
                    is.seekg (0, ios::beg);
                    html = new char [length];

                    is.read(html, length);
                    is.close();
                    cout << html;
                    delete[] html;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `html` is not null-terminated string, and `std::cout` keeps printing character until it finds `\0`, or it may crash your program

Do this:

```
html = new char [length +1 ];

is.read(html, length);
html[length] = '\0'; // put null at the end
is.close();
cout << html;
```

Or, you can do this:

```
cout.write(html, length);
```

`cout.write` will stop printing exactly after `length` number of chars.

Answer (score 7):

You didn't put a null terminator on your char array.  It's not ifstream reading too much, cout just doesn't know when to stop printing without the null terminator.

If you want to read an entire file, this is much easier:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
ifstream fin("index.html");
oss << fin.rdbuf();
std::string html = oss.str();
std::cout << html;
```

Comment: +1. IIRC the seek trick isn't even all that reliable for telling you the file size, especially if you're opening the file in text mode.